# mysql DB not adding rows with similar elements

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have created a DB with 3 columns: 
aid, qid and message.

aid is a foreign key which will be commond with another table.
comments is a varchar which stores user comments

its partially working. the problem is aid is not adding duplicate values. 
suppose i want to add comments related to specific aid. there are 18 aid's in all. and i want to filter the comments according to aid's. the table is not adding a duplicate aid.

this is the query I am using in php:

```
    $query = "UPDATE answers SET acount = acount + 1 WHERE aid = $vote";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $cadd = "INSERT INTO comments (aid, msg) VALUES ('$vote','$comment')";
    mysql_query($cadd);
```

what am i doing wrong. i am attaching a screenshot of the DB structure.

caution: extreme n00b.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the part of the page which describes the "indexes", which should reveal whether or not there's a primary key on comments.aid, which would prevent you from adding more than one row with the same aid. Alternatively, if you can't find it, can you paste in the results of "SHOW CREATE TABLE comments", which would include the same information?

Comment: In the first screenshot, click on Details (in the left-bottom corner of the screenshot area). Check what primary keys the table have, becose these usually are even unique fields.

Comment: should $vote be in quotes? It's an int field, right, so assuming the php variable $vote is an integer, you shouldn't need quotes around it -- i.e.:  $cadd = "INSERT INTO comments (aid, msg) VALUES ($vote,'$comment')";

Comment: can we have also a sql dump of the whole database? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like aid is your primary key, which should be unique.

Comment: i dont get it. please elaborate

Comment: aid is unique which means you cannot add duplicate aid numbers to that table.  If it is a foreign key in a one to many relationship then it should not be unique or a primary key.  It should just be a reference id to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Show table comments. I would guess the PK there is aid.
b.t.w your code is vulnerable to sql injection (unless this is only for the sake of debugging).

Comment: pls look at the question. the screenshot is of table comments